# Testing an update operation in RSpec, evaluates to true, but test fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this test:

```
it "saves the notification id in the referral for future reference" do
  expect { subject.perform(*args) }
    .to change(referral, :notification_id).from(nil).to(customer_notification_delivery.id)
end
```

And the code that it runs on top is:

```
if notification.present?
  referral.update(friend_customer_notification_delivery_id: notification.id)
end
```

I added a few debug messages, to check on them after firing the test, to ensure that this condition was being met, and the code was being run, and I got `true` for both

```
  p notification.present?
  p referral.update(friend_customer_notification_delivery_id: customer_notification_delivery.id)
```

Anything I am missing? Why the update returns true, but the value is not getting updated on the test?

The output I get:
`expected #notification_id to have changed from nil to 5, but did not change`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`referral` in your test and `referral` in your object-under-test are two different objects, I'm willing to bet. Changes to one do not affect the other. `referral` in the test does not magically pull up updates from the related database record made by some other code.

I normally do it like this

```
it "saves the notification id in the referral for future reference" do
  expect { subject.perform(*args) }
    .to change{ referral.reload.notification_id }.from(nil).to(customer_notification_delivery.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev, I tried reloading the model using only (referral.reload) did not work, using your approach (by also adding the attribute) I got a `TypeError:
       nil is not a symbol nor a string`

Comment: @queroga_vqz: try my approach exactly as shown

Comment: nevermind, i missed you also changed it to be a block, by using brackets. my bad, and thank you!